# Office.Interop.Word SaveAs says Invalid filename

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

Using Microsoft.Interop.Word I try to save a Word file (docx). In most cases it saves fine, but just occasionally it doesn't. And I can't figure out what specifically causes the error.

The file and path is generated, based on current related data. In this (failing) example the output file path (_fullpath in the c# code further down) is

> G:\Red Group\Varme\Tilbud_tilbudsprogram\108472_Test-Customer A_S
>   Projektafregning Kun til HE Pro Kolding \108472_Test-Customer
>   A_S Projektafregning Kun til HE Pro Kolding _201802062146.docx

The error message is "**Invalid filename**..."

The exception is:

> at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentClass.SaveAs2(Object&
>   FileName, Object& FileFormat, Object& LockComments, Object& Password,
>   Object& AddToRecentFiles, Object& WritePassword, Object&
>   ReadOnlyRecommended, Object& EmbedTrueTypeFonts, Object&
>   SaveNativePictureFormat, Object& SaveFormsData, Object&
>   SaveAsAOCELetter, Object& Encoding, Object& InsertLineBreaks, Object&
>   AllowSubstitutions, Object& LineEnding, Object& AddBiDiMarks, Object&
>   CompatibilityMode)     at Quotation.Word.OpenAndShow(String MergeFile,
>   String OutPath) in F:\dbConsult\Kunder\Danfoss\Quotation 2017\Danfoss
>   Quotation\Danfoss Quotation\Classes\WordMerge.cs:line 333

Line 333 is the wordDoc.SaveAs() line. That part of the code looks like this:

```
wordDoc.Activate();
wordApp.Visible = true;
wordApp.Activate();

try
    {
        wordDoc.SaveAs(_fullpath);
    }
catch (Exception ex)
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(_fullpath))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("Hey");
    }
    Helper.Log(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, "WordMerge.OpenAndShow()");
    return false;
}
```

The "using" part in my catch is for test. If I use the StreamWriter **the file is created as it should**. So, with this is mind I take that it is a flaw in the SaveAs() mehtod. Does that conclusion seem right? And if so: any clue what to do?

Best regards
Morten

Comment: Is this an app or an ASP website?

Comment: It is an app - Windows Forms.

Comment: Okay - got a bit further: In SOME cases the file will not save with too many spaces in path/file. The StreamWriter, however, seems just to eat it.

So, I've resolved the problem by replacing space characters:  Replace(" ", "-");

Comment: There's no problem with spaces, that won't make any difference. The path might be ttoo long though.

Comment: I actually log the file length - longest total path is 202. So that didn't seem to be it. I can just confirm that replacing " " with "-" makes it work. But thx for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by replacing space characters: Replace(" ", "-").

I cannot figure out exactly what triggers this, because I have plenty of successful saves without error occurring - and where I have spaces.

Also, all failed saves works well with StreamWriter. So it seems to be some internal flaw in the Word.Interop.

BR

Comment: Word's object model dates back to the 8.3 days - a time when spaces weren't allowed in file names. Since Word 97 longer file names, spaces, etc. were allowed, but sometimes the object model seems to "revert". I do regularly see Word change file paths for some things, substituting an "escape code" for spaces - %20 This linked discussion indicates it could have something to do with whether Word is seeing a UNC path: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/0d2ce868-97e2-4499-a259-f3e44413de52/how-to-access-a-folder-with-spaces-in-the-unc-path?forum=winservergen